# dashed-vertical-line child grouping extension in flutter code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, grouping, parent-child

I was watching a video about a flutter project in vs code, and I saw that the developer used an extension to group sections of widgets and its childs with a dashed-vertical-line on the left side. Does anyone know what extension is used here?

Answer (score 4):

That is not an extension. This is from VS code settings. Go to settings and search for FLUTTER UI you will get two options as shown in image. Select both option and restart your vs code. You will get broken line tree as you want.[image]

Comment: You also need to search for "Bazel" in the settings and check the option "Preview Bazel Worspace Custom Scripts"